# Font Awesome z-index issues

Tags: html, css, web, font-awesome

On a web project I'm working on I have a fixed navbar at the top of the page and the content underneath has Font Awesome icons sprinkled around.

Initially, I was using a CDN link to FA and everything was rendering fine.
When I tried using a local version retrieved through Bower, the icons were being rendered above the navbar while all other content was being rendered properly below.

The z-index on the icons are set to auto for both CDN and local versions (Font Awesome version 4.6.0).
I have tried modifying the icon z-index values manually to no avail.
The issue appears on both Firefox and Chrome.

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, I set the z-index for the navbar to 1000 and the FA icons are still getting shown on top of the fixed nav bar. Did anyone fix this yet?

Answer (score 3):

just recently came across this problem.

Apparently, font awesome icons has z-index: 4

Therefore, set .navbar to z-index: 5 or anything greatly than 4, the problem's gone.

Comment: Perfect, fixed my issue (y)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the stylesheets are being loaded in the same order - you can do this on the network tab.

Latency may be causing one stylesheet to apply out of order - especially if you are using imports.